# Enviar vários ID's num só request

Tags: android, json, request

A minha app é um QR Code scanner que quando lê um QR de um dispositivo faz um pedido ao servidor por um JSON.

Na actividade `DeviceInfo.class` é onde mostro toda a informação que quero referente ao QRCode scanneado. Falta-me agora criar um histórico que me mostre os últimos 20 dispositivos scanneados.

A minha dificuldade é em criar um histórico. Quero ir guardando os IDs dos dispositivos depois de serem scanneados. Na actividade `History.class` tenho um costum adapter onde quero mostrar os últimos dispositivos scanneados.

Não faço ideia como hei-de fazer para ir guardando os ID's internamente e quando iniciar a aplicação ela faça um pedido ao servidor para receber os 20 ID's e depois me devolver apenas o campo `designacao` para no costum adapter cada item ter o nome actualizado de cada dispositivo.

PS: Não tenho acesso aos controladores PHP do servidor

Home.class

```
public class Home extends ActionBarActivity {
    static final String ACTION_SCAN = "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        //Código responsável por remover a actionBar desta actividade
        //android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        //actionBar.hide();
    }

    //onClickMethod responsável por iniciar o QRScanner
    //atribuído ao botão scan_bt
    public void scanQR(View v) {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            //catch que chama o método showDialog quando o user nao tem o scanner
            //e questiona-o se prentede fazer download
            showDialog(Home.this, "No Scanner Found", "Download a scanner?", "Yes", "No").show();
        }
    }

    public void onBtn(View v){
        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id){
            case R.id.historyButton:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, History.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
                break;
        }
    }

    private static AlertDialog showDialog(final Activity act, CharSequence title, CharSequence message, CharSequence buttonYes, CharSequence buttonNo) {
        AlertDialog.Builder downloadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
        downloadDialog.setTitle(title);
        downloadDialog.setMessage(message);
        downloadDialog.setPositiveButton(buttonYes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:\" + \"com.google.zxing.client.android");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                try {
                    act.startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

                }

            }
        });

        downloadDialog.setNegativeButton(buttonNo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });

        return downloadDialog.show();
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");

                String[] resultado = contents.split("/");
                String id = resultado[resultado.length - 1];
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "ID: " + id + " Content: " + contents + " Format: " + format, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                toast.show();

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, DeviceInfo.class);

                myIntent.putExtra("ID_DISPOSITIVO", id);
                Log.d("MYLOG", "ID: " + id);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        }


    }

}
```

DeviceInfo.class

```
public class DeviceInfo extends ActionBarActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_info);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        String lol = getIntent().getStringExtra("ID_DISPOSITIVO");
        String url = "https://cc.streamline.pt/devices/view_json/" + lol;
        setTitle("My new title");

        Log.d("MYLOG", "lolID= " + lol + " e url= " + url);
        sslCertificates(url);

        final LinearLayout interfaceLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.interfaceLayout);
        Button interfaceButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.interfaceButton);
        interfaceButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (interfaceLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                            interfaceLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else {
                            interfaceLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );



    }


    //Classe responsável por "instalar" todos os certificados
    //para poder passar o de insegurança da streamline
    //e criação do jsonRequest e jsonObject
    public void sslCertificates(String s) {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {

                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        //No need to implement.
                    }

                    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        //No need to implement.
                    }
                }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        final TextView deviceTextView;
        final TextView soTextView;
        final TextView colabTextView;
        final TextView localTextView;
        final TextView facturaTextView;
        final TextView calendarioTextView;
        final TextView obsTextView;

        deviceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.deviceTextView);
        soTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.soTextView);
        colabTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colabTextView);
        localTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.localTextView);
        calendarioTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calendarioTextView);
        obsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.obsTextView);
        facturaTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.facturaTextView);


       final TextView designacaoInterface;
       designacaoInterface = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.designacaoInterface);

       final TextView tomadaInterface;
       tomadaInterface = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tomadaInterface);

       final TextView ipInterface;
       ipInterface = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ipInterface);

       final TextView macInterface;
       macInterface = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.macInterface);



        //Criação do objecto que vai fazer e receber o request de json
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, s, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    //Caso haja resposta do server
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {
                            Log.d("MYTAG", "Estou no try");

                            JSONObject desig = response.getJSONObject("Device");
                            String d_desig = desig.getString("designacao");
                            setTitle(d_desig);

                            //Criação do objecto que vai conter a informação da tabela device
                            JSONObject tipoMaquina = response.getJSONObject("TipoMaquina");
                            String t_designacao = tipoMaquina.getString("designacao");
                            deviceTextView.setText(t_designacao);

                            JSONObject sistemaOperativo = response.getJSONObject("Device");
                            String sO = sistemaOperativo.getString("so");
                            String sOv = sistemaOperativo.getString("so_versao");
                            soTextView.setText(sO + " " + sOv);

                            String dataEntrada = sistemaOperativo.getString("data_entrada");
                            calendarioTextView.setText(dataEntrada);

                            String obs = sistemaOperativo.getString("obs");
                            obsTextView.setText(obs);

                            JSONObject colab = response.getJSONObject("Colaboradore");
                            String colaborador = colab.getString("nome_preferido");
                            colabTextView.setText(colaborador);

                            JSONObject local = response.getJSONObject("Local");
                            String localS = local.getString("designacao");
                            localTextView.setText(localS);

                            JSONObject factura = response.getJSONObject("Factura");
                            String facturaS = factura.getString("designacao_full");
                            facturaTextView.setText(facturaS);


                            //AQUI ESTOU A LIDAR COM UM ARRAY, TENHO DE CRIAR UM OBJECTO
                            //PARA METER O ARRAY E DEPOIS IR AO OBJECTO bUSCAR ESSE ARRAY
                            JSONArray networkArray = response.getJSONArray("NetworkInterface");

                            for (int i=0; i<networkArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject inter = networkArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String designacao = inter.getString("designacao");
                                designacaoInterface.setText(designacao);

                                String tomada = inter.getString("tomada_bastidor");
                                tomadaInterface.setText(tomada);

                                String ip = inter.getString("ip");
                                ipInterface.setText(ip);

                                String mac = inter.getString("mac");
                                macInterface.setText(mac);
                            }



                            String jsonResponse = "";

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        Log.d("MYLOG", "response= " + response);

                    }
                },

                new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                       // mTextView.setText(error.toString());
                    }
                }
        );
        Log.d("LOL", "Saltei ate aqui");
        VolleyApplication.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(request);



    }
}
```

History.class

```
public class History extends ActionBarActivity{

    public
    ListView historyList;
    ArrayList<JSONBox> Data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

        Data = new ArrayList<JSONBox>();

        historyList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.historyList);

        historyList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            }
        });




        JSONBox j = new JSONBox("designacao");
        Data.add(j);

        JSONBox j1 = new JSONBox("designacao 2");
        Data.add(j1);


        ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem_history, Data);
        historyList.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Comment: Eu não percebi se queres uma forma de guardar um ficheiro, ou se queres que faça tudo que explicaste acima. Podes mostrar o código que já tens? E explicar melhor qual é o teu problema?

Comment: Vou editar o post para ser mais fácil, peço desculpa

Comment: Olha mas o servidor já te devolve os 20 últimos IDs?

Comment: Não, isso ia ser feito através da app. guardar os ID's, enviar para o servidor e receber a info que quero, ou receber o json completo.

Comment: Que tal criar uma tabela no banco de dados com os ID's?

Comment: Não tenho acesso à base de dados.

Comment: Estou a falar na app Android.

Comment: Como funcionaria isso? Tás a falar de guardar toda a informação sem ter de a requisitar toda a vez que quiser consultar?

Comment: Estava a falar só de guardar os ID's e depois fazeres as consultas na mesma.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm